# Task in a Multiproject Gradle Project that Depends on Multiple Subproject Gradle Plugin Tasks

Tags: android, gradle

I am working on a large build system where I have the following tasks:

```
:runTests

:moduleA:installDebug
:moduleA:installTest

:moduleB:installDebug
:moduleB:installTest

:moduleA:uninstallAll

:moduleB:uninstallAll
```

With the project / build structure:

```
build.gradle
settings.gradle
   |
   - moduleA
        |
        - build.gradle
   |
   - moduleB
        - build.gradle
```

The uninstallAll and install tasks are created by the Gradle android plugin.

I want `:runTests` to be an Exec type Gradle task that depends on `:moduleA:uninstallAll`, `:moduleB:uninstallAll`, `moduleA:installDebug`, and `moduleA:installTest` executed in that order.

I am attempting to configure this by using a `subproject` closure in the top level build.gradle file to create a single runTests Exec command that then uses dependsOn to specify that the uninstall and install tasks should be completed first.

However, this approach does not seem to work. Either the tasks created by the plugin are not found (even if they are listed with `gradlew tasks --all`) or the buildscript runs by the tasks are completely ignored.

What would be the best practice for creating this chain of dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the Android plugin creates tasks very late in the game, so you might have to wrap your logic in `gradle.projectsEvaluated { ... }`.